# Neighbourhood - Calculations

Tags: matrix, algorithm, performance-tuning

```
SeedRandom[0];
n = 5;
(m = N @ RandomInteger[{1, 3}, {n, n}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
result1 = MeanFilter[m, 1] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Since I want to write my own filters I tried to replicate the above

```
SeedRandom[0];
n = 5;
(m = ArrayPad[N @ RandomInteger[{1, 3}, {n, n}], 1, x]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
(t = Table[m[[r ;; r + 2, c ;; c + 2]], {r, 1, n}, {c, 1, n}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
result2 = Map[Mean, Map[Cases[#, _?NumberQ, 2] &, t, {2}], {2}] // MatrixForm;

result1 == result2
```

> True

So far so good.

The problem is  that the inbuilt `MeanFilter` is ten times faster as my code.

How can i accelerate my code?

Comment: I don't have MMA in front of me but I think ``Developer`PartitionMap`` may help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way is to use `ListConvolve`:

```
neighbors = 
  ListConvolve[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, m, {2, 2}, 0];
neighborCount = 
  ListConvolve[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, ConstantArray[1, Dimensions@m], {2, 2}, 0];

neighbors/neighborCount == MeanFilter[m, 1]
```

> `True`

However, for speed it's not so good to go over the entire matrix in order to figure out how many neighbors each piece has. Instead we fix that part explicitly:

```
{dimx, dimy} = Dimensions[m];
ker = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}/9 // N;
mean = ListConvolve[ker, m, {2, 2}, 0];
mean[[{1, 1, dimy, dimy}, {1, dimx, 1, dimx}]] = 
  9 mean[[{1, 1, dimy, dimy}, {1, dimx, 1, dimx}]]/4;
mean[[1, 2 ;; dimx - 1]] = 9 mean[[1, 2 ;; dimx - 1]]/6;
mean[[dimy, 2 ;; dimx - 1]] = 9 mean[[dimy, 2 ;; dimx - 1]]/6;
mean[[2 ;; dimy - 1, 1]] = 9 mean[[2 ;; dimy - 1, 1]]/6;
mean[[2 ;; dimy - 1, dimx]] = 9 mean[[2 ;; dimy - 1, dimx]]/6;
mean == MeanFilter[m, 1]
```

> `True`

When I compare `MeanFilter` and my last method on a matrix of size $10000\times 10000$ I get that `MeanFilter` consistently takes 6.9 seconds and the last method takes on average 6.7 seconds. **NICE!**

Comment: Nice but ... the MeanFilter[] programmer will get fired ..

Comment: BTW, Dera Pickett, How to understand the result of `ListCorrelate[{{u, v}, {p, q}}, {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}, {3,1}]` ,where $\{K_L,K_R\}=\{3,1\}$

Comment: @ShutaoTang It would be better to ask that as a separate question, I am sure many others would like a good explanation of it.

Comment: @Pickett,got it!  :-)